# Adding a parent to a static group from Search using Actions

Tags: groups

When creating a smart group, I have the option to add a parent to the smart group.
[image]

However, the same parent option doesn't show up when creating a static group from Search using Actions.
[image]

Is there a way to have the same 'Add Parent' functionality show up for static groups that are created from a Search?  Yes, I can change the settings of the group after creating the group so that the correct parent is assigned but I would rather be able to set this setting while creating the group.